# Splitting Graph into 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, discrete-mathematics

How can we split a weighted graph into 2 equal halves(both halves containing the same number of vertices) such that the total sum of removing edges in minimum?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're considering falls under the heading of "graph partitioning".  Almost any variant is at least NP-complete (unless your graphs have some special properties that help you out), so you'll probably have to resort to approximate heuristics if your graph is of nontrivial size.  From a practical point of view, I'd suggest just using some existing libraries.  The Wikipedia page gives a list of open-source packages, at least some of which are very sophisticated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition